# Is there a way to get the data from my User Interface to my main method? java

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, postfix-notation

This probably a stupid question, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the data from the User Interface to the main method. This is for a school project where I have to input data from a calculator in infix notation, and then output the result and the postfix notation expression. Sorry for the bad writing of the switch statement. Thanks in advance.

```
class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame{
    private String data;
    public CalculatorGUI gui = new CalculatorGUI();
    public void createAndShowUI(){
        // CalculatorGUI gui = new CalculatorGUI();
         CalculatorMenu menu = new CalculatorMenu(gui);
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reverse Polish Notation Calculator");
         frame.getContentPane().add(gui.getMainPanel());
         frame.setJMenuBar(menu.getJMenuBar());
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         if(gui.getIsDone()){
         //setData(gui);
         }
    }
    public void setData(CalculatorGUI gui){
        this.data = gui.getDisplay().getText();
    }
    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
class CalculatorGUI{
    private boolean isDone = false;
    private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 20);
    private static final String[][] STANDARD_BTN_TEXTS = {
            {"7", "8", "9", "/"}, {"4", "5", "6", "*"},
            {"1", "2", "3", "-"}, {"0", "%", "^", "+"},
            {"(",")","n!","ln","ENTER"}};
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField display = new JTextField();
    CalculatorGUI(){
        display.setFont(BTN_FONT);
        JPanel standardPanel = createBtnPanel(STANDARD_BTN_TEXTS, "Reverse Polish Notation");
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.add(standardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    public boolean getIsDone(){
        return isDone;
    }
    public void setIsDone(boolean bool){
        this.isDone=bool;
    }
    public String sendData(){
        return display.getText();
    }
    public JPanel getMainPanel(){
        return mainPanel;
    }
    public JTextField getDisplay(){
        return display;
    }
    private JPanel createBtnPanel(String[][] texts, String title) {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        int rows = texts.length;
        int cols = texts[0].length;
        ButtonAction command = new ButtonAction();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));
        for (int row = 0; row < texts.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < texts[row].length; col++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(texts[row][col]);
                btn.setFont(BTN_FONT);
                btn.addActionListener(command);
                btnPanel.add(btn);
            }
        }
        btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return btnPanel;
    }
    private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            switch(command){
            case "0": display.setText(display.getText()+"0"); 
break; case "1": display.setText(display.getText()+"1"); break; 
            case "2": display.setText(display.getText()+"2"); break; case "3": display.setText(display.getText()+"3");break;
            case "4":display.setText(display.getText()+"4"); break;case "5": display.setText(display.getText()+"5");break;
            case "6": display.setText(display.getText()+"6");break;case "7": display.setText(display.getText()+"7");break;
            case "8": display.setText(display.getText()+"8");break;case "9": display.setText(display.getText()+"9");break;
            case "(":display.setText(display.getText()+"(");break;case ")":display.setText(display.getText()+")");break;
            case "^":display.setText(display.getText()+"^");break;case "*":display.setText(display.getText()+"*");break;
            case "/":display.setText(display.getText()+"/");break;case "+":display.setText(display.getText()+"+");break;
            case "-":display.setText(display.getText()+"-");break;case "ENTER":setIsDone(true);break;
            }
        }
    }
}
class CalculatorMenu{

    private static final String STANDARD = "Standard";
    private CalculatorGUI gui;
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenuItem standardView;

    CalculatorMenu(CalculatorGUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        standardView = new JMenuItem(STANDARD, KeyEvent.VK_T);
        //scientificView = new JMenuItem(SCIENTIFIC, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        ViewAction viewAction = new ViewAction();
        standardView.addActionListener(viewAction);
        standardView.setEnabled(false);
        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        viewMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        viewMenu.add(standardView);
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Edit"));
        menuBar.add(viewMenu);
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Help"));
    }

    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    private class ViewAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if (command.equals(STANDARD)) {
                standardView.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class RPN {
    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int operatorLength;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CalculatorFrame calc = new CalculatorFrame();
         //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             //public void run() {
                calc.createAndShowUI();
             //}
          //});
        //System.out.print("Enter the operation in infix notation: ");
        String infixString =calc.gui.getDisplay().getText();// keyboard.nextLine();
        //infixString = infixString.trim();
        LinkListStack infixLinkStack = new LinkListStack();
        Stack infixArrayStack = new Stack(infixString.length());
        Stack postfixArrayStack = new Stack(infixString.length());
        operatorLength = getOperatorLength(infixString);
        infixLinkStack = addToStack(infixString);
        infixArrayStack = addToArrayStack(infixLinkStack);
        infixArrayStack = deleteNullValues(infixArrayStack);
        //String postfixString = convertToPostfix(infixArrayStack);
        //System.out.println("posftixString: "+postfixString);
        postfixArrayStack =convertToPostfix(infixArrayStack);// pushStringToArrayStack(postfixString);
        postfixArrayStack.displayStack();
        long result = computePostfixExpression(postfixArrayStack);
        System.out.println("result: "+result);
    }
```

Comment: "_how to get the data from the User Interface to the main method_" I don't see a main method.

Comment: Nor should you want to get the result to the main method. This is an event-driven GUI program, and with these programs the main method should be used for creating the main objects, connect them, start them running, and then move out of the way. Display your output in the GUI.

Comment: As a sidenote: you don't need the switch statement; you can just use `display.setText(display.getText()+command)` in all cases except the ENTER. That should improve the readability considerably.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it is possible, but that is not the solution to your problem. Think about the main method as a sort of the green-light for your program. It tells it to go, it is not the driver.

*Create an OnClick method that uses `findViewById()` to reference your data field containing the string you want to manipulate from infix to postfix. When you create a reference to your component, you can use the `getText()` method to pull your string out of that component and use your `InfixToPostfix(myString)` method. Then, with a reference to the component you want to use to display the data, call the `.setText(ResultOfInfixToPostFix)`*.

**EDIT FOR SWING IN JAVA:** 
sorry about writing the solution in android, I've been doing some projects and got the two jumbled in my head. As for an on-click solution, heres how it would work in Swing for Java.

In your code, you should have your text field, and your button declared in some format of:

```
private JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
makeInfixButton = new JButton("Make Table!");
```

What you want is to execute your calculation on your text field entry on a button press, so you want to add an `ActionListener` to your button. Here is an example:

```
makeInfixButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ConvertPostFixToInfix(myTextField.getText.toString())
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you link me to a post regarding formatting so that I don't repeat the mistake?

Comment: `onClick()`? `fineViewById()`? Which GUI library are you referring to? It looks like you're trying to give an Android answer to a Swing question.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I misread the tag. I'll edit this for swing when I finish driving.

Comment: Hello, I think I came up with a solution, but I think yours would work better. If you could let me know about those methods I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! Basically I just included a boolean function to check if ENTER had been hit, if so, the the data was sent to the frame, and from there to my main method and RPN class, where I can compute it. Now I just need to find a way to output the result and the postfix string in the display.

The new methods are in CalculatorGUI class, getIsDone() and sendData(). the while loop is in the frame class.

Just in case someone else has the same problem, here is my new code:

```
class CalculatorFrame extends JFrame{
    private String data;
    public CalculatorGUI gui = new CalculatorGUI();
    public void createAndShowUI(){
         CalculatorMenu menu = new CalculatorMenu(gui);
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reverse Polish Notation Calculator");
         frame.getContentPane().add(gui.getMainPanel());
         frame.setJMenuBar(menu.getJMenuBar());
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         while(gui.getIsDone()==false){
             //if(gui.sendData()){
                 data += gui.sendData();
            // }
         }
    }
    public void setData(CalculatorGUI gui){
        this.data = gui.getDisplay().getText();
    }
    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
class CalculatorGUI{
    private boolean isDone = false;
    private static final Font BTN_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 20);
    private static final String[][] STANDARD_BTN_TEXTS = {
            {"7", "8", "9", "/"}, {"4", "5", "6", "*"},
            {"1", "2", "3", "-"}, {"0", "%", "^", "+"},
            {"(",")","n!","ln","ENTER"}};
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField display = new JTextField();
    CalculatorGUI(){
        display.setFont(BTN_FONT);
        JPanel standardPanel = createBtnPanel(STANDARD_BTN_TEXTS, "Reverse Polish Notation");
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        mainPanel.add(standardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    public boolean getIsDone(){
        return isDone;
    }
    public void setIsDone(boolean bool){
        System.out.println("Set is done activated");
        this.isDone=bool;
    }
    public String sendData(){
        if(isDone){
        System.out.println("send data activated");
        return display.getText();
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }
    public JPanel getMainPanel(){
        return mainPanel;
    }
    public JTextField getDisplay(){
        return display;
    }
    private JPanel createBtnPanel(String[][] texts, String title) {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        int rows = texts.length;
        int cols = texts[0].length;
        ButtonAction command = new ButtonAction();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));
        for (int row = 0; row < texts.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < texts[row].length; col++) {
                JButton btn = new JButton(texts[row][col]);
                btn.setFont(BTN_FONT);
                btn.addActionListener(command);
                btnPanel.add(btn);
            }
        }
        btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return btnPanel;
    }
    private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            //display.setText(display.getText()+command)
            switch(command){
            case "0": display.setText(display.getText()+"0"); break; case "1": display.setText(display.getText()+"1"); break; 
            case "2": display.setText(display.getText()+"2"); break; case "3": display.setText(display.getText()+"3");break;
            case "4":display.setText(display.getText()+"4"); break;case "5": display.setText(display.getText()+"5");break;
            case "6": display.setText(display.getText()+"6");break;case "7": display.setText(display.getText()+"7");break;
            case "8": display.setText(display.getText()+"8");break;case "9": display.setText(display.getText()+"9");break;
            case "(":display.setText(display.getText()+"(");break;case ")":display.setText(display.getText()+")");break;
            case "^":display.setText(display.getText()+"^");break;case "*":display.setText(display.getText()+"*");break;
            case "/":display.setText(display.getText()+"/");break;case "+":display.setText(display.getText()+"+");break;
            case "-":display.setText(display.getText()+"-");break;case "ENTER":setIsDone(true);break;
            }
        }
    }
}
class CalculatorMenu{

    private static final String STANDARD = "Standard";
    private CalculatorGUI gui;
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenuItem standardView;

    CalculatorMenu(CalculatorGUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
        standardView = new JMenuItem(STANDARD, KeyEvent.VK_T);
        //scientificView = new JMenuItem(SCIENTIFIC, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        ViewAction viewAction = new ViewAction();
        standardView.addActionListener(viewAction);
        standardView.setEnabled(false);
        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        viewMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        viewMenu.add(standardView);
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Edit"));
        menuBar.add(viewMenu);
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("Help"));
    }

    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    private class ViewAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String command = e.getActionCommand();
            if (command.equals(STANDARD)) {
                standardView.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class RPN {
    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int operatorLength;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CalculatorFrame calc = new CalculatorFrame();
         //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             //public void run() {
         calc.createAndShowUI();
        //System.out.print("Enter the operation in infix notation: ");
        String infixString =calc.getData();// keyboard.nextLine();
        //infixString = infixString.trim();
        LinkListStack infixLinkStack = new LinkListStack();
        Stack infixArrayStack = new Stack(infixString.length());
        Stack postfixArrayStack = new Stack(infixString.length());
        operatorLength = getOperatorLength(infixString);
        infixLinkStack = addToStack(infixString);
        infixArrayStack = addToArrayStack(infixLinkStack);
        infixArrayStack = deleteNullValues(infixArrayStack);
        //String postfixString = convertToPostfix(infixArrayStack);
        //System.out.println("posftixString: "+postfixString);
        postfixArrayStack =convertToPostfix(infixArrayStack);// pushStringToArrayStack(postfixString);
        postfixArrayStack.displayStack();
        long result = computePostfixExpression(postfixArrayStack);
        System.out.println("result: "+result);
    }
```